# Java app hangs after reading data from 90k+ files to be written to excel

Tags: java

I'm working on a project to extract some data out of a lot of machine generated files (100k+ totaling 15gig) to excel (2003) one file per row. I'm loading all the files in-memory into an array list before writing each file's data extracted per row into an excel(using JExcel API).

Everything works ok till about 90k files have been read and written to the open workbook  then it stops working.

I execute workbook.write() and  and workbook.close()  after all files have been read and extracted as such nothing gets written to the actual file on disk when it "hangs".

No error are thrown. Any ideas on resolving this issue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to post some code if you want help. Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Have you looked at the machine's performance? Are you paging to disk (e.g. the VM isn't out of memory, but your RAM is full?).

Comment: BTW, why aren't you just writing the workbooks out as you read them in? If you read in everything, but like you said, the app fails 90% of the way there, at least you would end up with 90k workbooks, instead of having to start over from the beginning every time.

Comment: And why are you loading entire files rather than reading one line at a time? All you're doing is wasting memory and adding latency.

Comment: @John3136 the app worked perferctly for smaller file sets (< 1k) so I figured the issue was not with the code.

Comment: @normalocity i needed to have just one workbook with one worksheet in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible problems:

1. Java or Excel is running out of memory

   - You can fix this by writing to the Workbook as you read each file in, instead of storing them all in memory
2. Excel is running out of rows

   - If this is the case, there's basically nothing you can do...

Why does it need to be directly into Excel, anyway? You might be better off writing the whole thing directly to a `CSV` file which Excel knows how to open natively...

Comment: Many thanks @durron597, I investigated both issues and it turns out excel may have run out rows...I have switched to CSV though and things are working ok now ;) thanks.